# Why laravel do not work properly with ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, laravel-8

I try to do social media app with using laravel and during to making like system I used ajax on my js file. I get so many interesting mistakes so I want to share all of them with you. I really feel helpless about this and I searched this whole day. Thanks for all helps.

1. First, I try to get data from which is postId and like state but it looks undefined when I took alert on the success function of ajax.
2. Second, router can not post generally and ajax acts different during test. Thats way I moved my code from mainpage.js to main.blade.php still not work properly.
3. Third, when I closed console during test and click to like button, page refresh itself.

this is like part of my main.blade.php

```
                       <form id="like" >
                        @csrf
                          <a  value="{{$posts->Id}}"  type="submit"  class="card-link"><i class="fa fa-gittip" ></i> Like</a>
                          <button id="likepost" value="{{$posts->Id}}" type="submit"></button>
                            </form>
                            <a id="showcomments" class="card-link"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> Comments</a>
                        </div>
```

this is my function from postcontroller.php

```
function likeposts(Request $request){
  

  dd($request);
   }
```

this is my web router part:

```
Route::post('/post', [PostController::class, 'likeposts'])->name('post');
```

I followed tutorial (but it's not laravel-8) so It's my ajax part from main.blade.php :

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
           
           $("#like").submit(function(event){
              // Do global setting.
              event.preventDefault();
              console.log(event);
              var Id=document.getElementById('likepost').value;
              alert(Id);
           var like =like();
              $.ajaxSetup({
               headers: {
                   'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                 }, 
               method:'POST',
               url:"/post",
               data:{ like:like,postId:Id},
              });$.ajax( {
               success:function(data) {
                  alert("ok");
               }
                  
             
           });
        });
       
       })
```

Thanks again all helps!

Comment: `<a  value="{{$posts->Id}}"  type="submit"...`??? Mixing `<a>` and `<input>` attributes?

Comment: Yes, I try to turned it to form. Actually I care about just button which has id "likepost".

Answer (score 0):

You can modify html like below

```
 <a href="#" data-postid="{{$posts->Id}}" class="card-link likeButton" i><i class="fa fa-gittip"></i> Like</a>


    <a id="showcomments" class="card-link"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> Comments</a>
```

and in ajax

```
 <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
    
                $('.likeButton').on('click',function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var csrf = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
                    var postId=$(this).attr('data-postid')
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "{{route('post')}}",
                        method: 'POST',
                        data: {_token: csrf, postId: postId},
                        success: function () {
                           
                        }
                    });
    
                })
    
         
    
            })
        </script>
```

and don't forget to add meta tag

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

Comment: I pasted to my files and still postcontroller can not run dd() function .Plus one of them my post run success function and alert to ok to me but  others just throw away to me top of the page. (I am using blade with foreach for getting from database)

Comment: dd($request->all()); and also check what you get

Comment: @Doctorstarter .post full blade code. as per my understanding it should work

Comment: @Doctorstarter.i have updated code .ite my wrong in code. again copy both html and js

Comment: It's works for getting like action but still dd() function not working.

Comment: my main blade is so long for posting.(over 700 line) I am using blade template and html for showing posts on the main blade and like button code is inside of foreach  . Also I have some query for database with DB:: facade in the main blade. @JohnLobo

Comment: It can be game changer, my javascript part is below the all of codes.